# Uploading a recorded audio file using phonegap (Android)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hello There,
             I am new to phonegap.I am trying to record a audio clip and uploading it to server.I am working with phonegap +jquery mobile + Android.Can anyone tell me a good way which can work for me with a small example.Basically I have a form which have a button as Record, from which user can record an audio clip and can publish it.So basically I need to upload that recorded file on server on submitting the form.I tried phonegap API's Media and File for recording and uploading file but couldn't succeed.

I am using following function for recording :

```
function recordAudio() {
        var src = "myrecording.mp3";
        var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
        // Record audio
        mediaRec.startRecord();

        // Stop recording after 10 sec
        var recTime = 0;
        var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
            recTime = recTime + 1;
            setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
            if (recTime >= 10) {
                clearInterval(recInterval);
                mediaRec.stopRecord();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Now I need to upload this recorded file to server.I am testing on emulator.

Kind Regrads
Jaya

Comment: Not a lot of info on what you tried and what went wrong.. Did you try PhoneGap's FileTransfer upload method? Their code example shows uploading an image, but sub'ing audio capture instead should be easy. Not sure why you need a form.

Comment: jaya have you found the way by which we can upload our audio file on server. if yes then please tell me it. i also want to do same thing.

Comment: @Libby sir, jaya wants to upload file to server.Now clear the question ? now give the answer if you have any ideaaa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default location of recorded audio for android is "mnt/sdcard/myrecording.wav" 
to upload, use the `FileTransfer` object to upload the audio

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload("mnt/sdcard/myrecording.wav", "http://www.website.com/upload.php", win, fail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the captureAudio function directly?

```
function captureAudio() {
   // Launch device audio recorder
   navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError);
}
```

Check here: [PhoneGap Doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio)

Under captureSuccess callback, you could use the FileTransfer object to upload your file.